# Windows Batch Script - Parse String D:\Datacom\Pass from D:\Datacom\Pass\tomcat\bin\tomcat7.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

How to parse a string in batch script.

I want to parse `D:\Datacom\Pass` from `D:\Datacom\Pass\tomcat\bin\tomcat7.exe` and assign to a variable.

I tried following code,

```
set pass_path=D:\Datacom\Pass\tomcat\bin\tomcat7.exe
set var1=%pass_path%
set var2=%var1:*Pass=%
echo %var2%
```

it returns

> ```
> \tomcat\bin\tomcat7.exe
> ```

but I want the first part.

> ```
> D:\Datacom\Pass
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```cmd
rem // Append a character not present in string:
set "var1=%pass_path%|"
rem // Split off first part to get augmented last part:
set "var2=%var1:*\Pass\=\%"
rem // Split off augmented last part:
call set "var3=%%var1:%var2%=%%"
rem // Return result:
echo %var3%
```

This will work reliably only since the input string itself is expected not to contain `|`.

---

Alternatively, you could do this:

```cmd
rem // Replace partial string by character not present in string:
set "var1=%pass_path:\Pass\=|%"
rem // Split altered string at that character:
for /F "tokens=1 delims=| eol=|" %%I in ("%var1%") do (
    set "var2=%%I"
)
rem // Append replaced partial string:
set "var3=%var2%\Pass"
rem // Return result:
echo %var3%
```

Also this relies on the assumption that the input string does not contain `|`.